# What's the difference between list1 = [] list2 = [] and list1 = list2 = [] in python?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I just started using python and I am trying to initialize two lists using list comprehensions. Like this

```
list1 = list2 = [0.0] * 57
```

When i do this and insert these lists with values i am getting a different set of values (incorrect values) when compared to the values i get when i initialize these lists seperately. Like

```
list1 = [0.0] * 57
list2 = [0.0] * 57
```

What is happening in the first case ? Why am I getting different answers for these 2 cases ?

Comment: My guess is that the RHS of the equation gets evaluated first and then the LHS.  I don't know the order of evaluation in the interpreter though.

Comment: @squiguy Nope, it's that both variables get bound to the *same* list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the following case, you are creating one list and making 2 variables point to it; i.e. 2 references to the same object:

```
list1 = list2 = [123] * 3
list1.append(456)

print list1 =>  # prints [123, 123, 123, 456]
print list2 =>  # prints [123, 123, 123, 456]
print list1 is list2   # prints True
```

whereas this creates 2 new lists and assigns one to `list1` and the other to `list2`:

```
list1 = [123] * 3
list2 = [123] * 3
# or  list1, list2 = [123] * 3, [123] * 3

list1.append(456)

print list1  # prints [123, 123, 123, 456]
print list2  # prints [123, 123, 123]
print list1 is list 2  # prints False
```

This has to do with whether values are copied or stored in variables by reference. In the case of immutable objects such as integers and strings, this doesn't matter:

```
# a and b contain the same int object
# but it's OK because int's are immutable
a = b = 1
a += 2  # creates a new int from 1+2 and assigns it to `a`
print b  # => 1  ... b is unchanged
print a  # => 3
```

In other words, `int`s (nor `float`s nor `str`s etc) have no methods that change the value you're calling the method on; instead, they all return new instances of that type; so `-5` returns a new int `-5` not the existing int `5` modified; also, `a += 2` is equivalent to `a = a + 2` where `a + 2` (i.e the method `__add__` called on a) returns a fresh int whose value is `a + 2` and a reference to that gets assigned back to `a`.

Answer (score 6):

The first one sets `list1` and `list2` to both refer to the *same* list. The second one defines a new list for each name.

Comment: Ohh. Got it. Thanks! Just a follow up on this, this method seems to work perfectly when using plain numbers like num1 = num2 = num3 = 0.0 has no problems whatsover. Why is that ?

Comment: @Pradep: Numbers (and strings and a few other datatypes) are immutable. You can't change the value of `0`, but you can change the elements of a list. That's why this matters.